# How to put parameters obtained through "pandas.describe" in a plot in one go?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Like if i have a data frame with four columns and i want to plot any two columns of it just to visualize my data. And we can find the value of all the parameters by using this

```
pd.describe()

count     332.000000
mean     5645.999337
std       391.081389
min      4952.290000
25%      5294.402500
50%      5647.905000
75%      6028.805000
max      6290.980000
```

Now, how can we put the information that we get with this function ('pandas.describe') into the plot in just one go. Instead of using the usual 'label' function from matplotlib. [image]

Comment: What kind of plot do you want?  Can you include a picture of your desired plot?

Comment: yes of course.! Actually i'm trying to make a plot with linear fit, so i'm using 'seaborn' and see the  picture to check how it looks.

Comment: What you want is having describe info as some kind of legend? Am I understanding right?

Comment: yes you got it right.! I wasn't able to put it in right words. @JuanC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib has the option ax.text. So you need to convert this info into text.
Here comes an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]})
desc=df.describe()
```

Describe is also a DataFrame, you can turn every column into a string list:

```
data1=[i for i in desc.index]
data2=[str(i) for i in desc.A]
```

Now you can join both with a colon in between:

```
text= ('\n'.join([ a +':'+ b for a,b in zip(data1,data2)]))
```

Then in your graph, you can input:

```
 ax.text(pos1, pos2, text , fontsize=15)
```

Where `pos1` and `pos2`are numbers for the position of your text.
Does that help?
Tell me!